# How to link Nokia Maps marker?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I mean click on a marker redirects to new url. There are many tutorials about Google Maps only. I need sample code, which I can't find on Nokia Maps API developers help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a listener to the "click"

To click on a marker and get a pop-up with a link:

```
  var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
  map.addComponent( infoBubbles);
  var marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(center, {
    $html: "<a href='your link'>http://www.example.com</a>"
    });

marker.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) { 
    infoBubbles.addBubble(evt.target.$html, evt.target.coordinate);          
    }, false);  

map.objects.add(marker);
```

For a direct link just use:

```
    var marker2 = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(center);
    marker2.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) { 
        window.location = 'http://www.example.com'; 
}, false);
```